# Make the package usueful

Tags: ros, catkin, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just finish working a project in ROS.

What I want to do actually is to make my package useful for another people, my package contain a node and big library.
Like when I give the package to someone, he can use it without any problem.

So the question is how can I take the package to another computer and what should do in it so that the package works fine ?

(I'm using catkin package.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187795/make-the-package-usueful/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-07-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-25**:
So what's your question?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-25**:
the question is clear but anyway I just add one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just copy-paste your project (the folder `catkin_workspace/src/project`) into the other person's `catkin_workspace/src` folder. Go to the top level catkin_workspace directory and hit `catkin_make`.

That is all that is needed. (Of course, assuming all dependencies, ROS and external, are satisfied.)

It is nice to use git-github. So that everything becomes easy.

Have a great day!

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-25**:
two questions : 1- Go to the top level catkin_workspace directory, where is that ? 2- "It is nice to use git-github. So that everything becomes easy." you mean that I could share my package in git-github website ?

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-25**:
Git is a version control software. You can find tutorials here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Git/article.html.

The top level catkin_workspace is the directory from where you type catkin_make. It is the directory that has src, devel, build and CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to publish your package for other developers in the community to use and contribute to, the first thing to do is to make the source code freely available for download. If you don't already have version control, https://github.com is usually a good choice. The [recommended repository useage](http://wiki.ros.org/RecommendedRepositoryUsage) page on the wiki has some good guidelines on how to use github effectively with ROS.

Once you have your package available for download, the next step is to [add it to the repository index](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation) and create a wiki page with some basic documentation about how to use your package.

The [Getting Involved](http://wiki.ros.org/Get%20Involved) page on the wiki has some more general information about participating in the community that you may find interesting as well.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2